# nfs: what does it mean the "-" character?

Tags: nfs

On `man exports` I see

```
/srv/www        -sync,rw server @trusted @external(ro)
```

what does it mean the "-" before the options sync and rw?

Comment: It's written right there, at the same exports man pages you brought the example from... `Also, each line may have one or more specifications for default options after the path name, in the form of a dash ("-") followed by an option list. The option list is used for all subsequent exports on that line only`

Comment: Add as answer so I can close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's written right there, at the same exports man pages you brought the example from:

> Also, each line may have one or more specifications for default options after the path name, in the form of a dash ("`-`") followed by an option list. The option list is used for all subsequent exports on that line only.